# WAIT for "1 of many process" to finish

Tags: bash, wait

Is there any built in feature in bash to wait for 1 out of many processes to finish? And then kill remaining processes?

```
pids=""
# Run five concurrent processes
for i in {1..5}; do
        ( longprocess ) &
        # store PID of process
        pids+=" $!"
done

if [ "one of them finished" ]; then
        kill_rest_of_them;
fi
```

I'm looking for "one of them finished" command. Is there any?

Comment: Are they children of the current shell?

Comment: I call programs and scripts inside functions in current shell

Comment: This [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) page may be of help here.

Answer (score 13):

`bash` 4.3 added a `-n` flag to the built-in `wait` command, which causes the script to wait for the next child to complete. The `-p` option to `jobs` also means you don't need to store the list of pids, as long as there aren't any background jobs that you *don't* want to wait on.

```
# Run five concurrent processes
for i in {1..5}; do
    ( longprocess ) &
done

wait -n
kill $(jobs -p)
```

Note that if there is another background job other than the 5 long processes that completes first, `wait -n` will exit when it completes. That would also mean you would still want to save the list of process ids to kill, rather than killing whatever `jobs -p` returns.

Comment: *`bash` 4.3 added a `-n` flag to the built-in `wait` command...* I wish I'd had that option a few years back...

Answer (score 4):

It's actually fairly easy:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o monitor
killAll()
{
# code to kill all child processes
}

# call function to kill all children on SIGCHLD from the first one
trap killAll SIGCHLD

# start your child processes here

# now wait for them to finish
wait
```

You just have to be *really* careful in your script to use only bash built-in commands.  You can't start *any* utilities that run as a separate process after you issue the `trap` command - any child process exiting will send `SIGCHLD` - and you can't tell where it came from.

Comment: Certainly possible to distinguish other SIGCHLDs. Store a list of your background processes (`foo & foo_pids+=( $! )`), and check if any of them are dead when you get a SIGCHLD (via `kill -0`). Everyone's alive -> it came from somewhere else.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nice.  I wish I'd thought of that when I had to hack together a script for a customer similar to what I posted above, all under extreme time pressure.

Comment: A new special parameter (perhaps `$&`) containing the process ID of the child the caused `SIGCHILD` (or that caused `wait -n` to exit) would be nice. Maybe I'll make a feature request for 4.5